# Issues starting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I'm having some issues starting a rails server for a new project. I've been successful starting a rails server for a project in the same folder. I tried this outside of the folder and the issue remains. I've updated ruby, updated RVM, updated the bundler version and still nothing works.

Here's the error I keep getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    26: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    25: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /Users/semira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Users/semira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    22: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    20: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    19: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    18: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    17: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    16: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    15: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    13: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    11: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:67:in `require_relative'
     5: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     4: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     3: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     1: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    28: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    26: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /Users/semira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /Users/semira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    21: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:67:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:40:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     2: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
    28: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    27: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    26: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    25: from /Users/semira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /Users/semira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    23: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    21: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    19: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    18: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    17: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    16: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    15: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    14: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    12: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    10: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     8: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:67:in `require_relative'
     6: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
     4: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
     3: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     2: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     1: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:9:in `require': cannot load such file -- msgpack/2.6/msgpack (LoadError)
    29: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    28: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    27: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    26: from /Users/semira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    25: from /Users/semira/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    24: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    23: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    22: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    20: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    19: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    18: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    17: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    16: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/bin/rails:8:in `require_relative'
    15: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    14: from /Users/semira/rails_studio/admin/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
    13: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    11: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap.rb:3:in `require_relative'
     9: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:67:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache.rb:67:in `require_relative'
     7: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     6: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:39:in `with_gems'
     5: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/explicit_require.rb:43:in `rescue in with_gems'
     4: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
     3: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/store.rb:3:in `require'
     2: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack.rb:11:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/semira/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/msgpack-1.2.6/lib/msgpack/msgpack.bundle (LoadError)
```

Comment: Just fixed this issue! I emptied the gem set  then used 
bundle install

Comment: what do you mean exactly by that?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue while booting `rails server`. So i installed the latest `msgpack` gem, That resolved my issue. Use the below command to install the latest version of gem `msgpack`

```
gem install msgpack -v 1.3.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Main reason for this issue is incompatible gem version. This issue occurs when the gem version clashes between two different rails projects. I would recommend you to use Ruby Version Manager `rvm` which can be used to create virtual environments for each rails project.

**How to avoid these issue:**

- Use `rvm gemset` which gives you compartmentalised independent ruby setups.

**Example:**

- Once you installed `rvm` you can download any version of ruby using command `rvm install ruby-2.6.3`
- Use command `rvm use 2.6.3` to activate specific ruby version.
- If you are creating a new project in rails say `test_project` make sure you are also creating a `gemset` with the same name. e.g: `rvm gemset create test_project`
- Use command `rvm use 2.6.3@test_project` to activate the gameset.
- Once you complete all the above steps follow the procedure you normally use for installing gems. e.g: `gem install bundler` and `bundle install`

**Note:**

- Make sure to activate the `gemset` before starting up the rails server for your project. e.g: `rvm use 2.6.3@test_project`

Hope this solves your issue.